# Why "no such table: django_session" when trying to use admin?

Tags: django

I am pretty sure that database has been created and I have executed `python manage.py syncdb` properly but still i encounter this error when trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/. Here are some details.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/
Exception Value: no such table: django_session
```

Comment: Can you see the table in your db?  What engine are you using?

Comment: I'd bet that you haven't run `syncdb` - does running that fix the problem?

Comment: Ah.. My usual mistakes. i skipped the part where it read use forward slashes in path EVEN ON WINDOWS.

Answer (score 4):

path to sqlite is usually the problem.

```
'NAME': 'c:/path/to/sqlite.db'
```

Answer (score 4):

Make migrations will solve the problem.

Run below commands:

```
python ./manage.py migrate

python ./manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
ROOT = dirname(abspath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

print "self.__name__: " + __name__
print "self.__file__: " + __file__
print "ROOT: " + ROOT

import django
print "django.__path__: " 
print (django.__path__)

# Contact for error messages etc. - dont forget the ',' after the first entry

ADMINS = (('dev', 'dev@example.com'),)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',        
'NAME': ROOT + 'project.db',                      
    'USER': '',    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',    'PORT': '',                      
}
}
```

and check if you need  + '/' +  before the database name for your operating system.

Comment: peters approach worked for me, although using linux and having my db located in the same dir as `manage.py` i changed the second line to `ROOT = dirname(abspath(__file__ + '/..')) + '/'`

Answer (score 1):

`SESSION_ENGINE` it's using `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db` by default and that's make you need to :

1. put `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` list variable in `settings.py`
2. you must migrate your database

if you don't want to do that, just put `SESSION_ENGINE` to `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache` in your `settings.py`.

so, in your `settings.py` like this :

```
...
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
...
```

by the way, as in the documentation say :

> '..the simple cache is faster because it disregards persistence.'

you can cek in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

If you have added/updated table in any models.py file, you might need to migrate the db before running the server.

Run below commands before running 'python manage.py runserver':

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: I think that generating migrations after the `migrate` command would make you run again the `migrate`

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you run the server without a database created or the session table inside of it (in case you recently add the `admin` app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`). In order to create the database or the table run this command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

In older versions of django  is this command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

It prompted you to that error page because your Database wasn't even created, which lead to the absence of the mandatory tables to access the admin page.

Run the following two commands :

```
python3 manage.py migrate

python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

Running the first command actually creates your database which holds the necessary starter tables. I had the same problem and this solved 100% for me.

Solution source : @satya 's answer

Answer (score -1):

Executing in the below order works fine:

First

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

Then

```
 python manage.py runserver.
```

Since we are applying all migrations before running the server.